# how to multiply a data row "foundRows" with a value using if condtion

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
var strExpr = "Quan > 0";
var strSort = "Quan DESC";
var foundRows = ds.Tables[0].Select(strExpr,strSort);
var no = 0;
//foundRows = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey());
if (no >= 0 && no <= 499)
{
    result = foundRows * no;
    Console.WriteLine("\n{0} * {1} = {2}", foundRows, 10, result);
}
```

Trying to multiply datarow" foundrows" with a value based on condition(greater or less than). The above code is not getting build successfully and displaying the below error
"Operator * cannot be applied to operands of type DataRow[] and int"

Comment: foundRows contains rows of table. You need to take count in another variable and use that , like var cnt = foundRows.Count;

Comment: Awesome. Followed the steps and it worked